# Is there a way to update a Slate change after the current change completes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slate, slatejs

Basically I want to make inlines that can be updated from the end if the cursor/selection is there. However it seems to be overriding changes like deleting from the end an inline.

I was attempting to do something like this (with guidance from slate-sticky-inline)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fj9dvhom/963/) or what I think is the relevant code below

```
const onChange = change => {
    //Not in a inline but at the start of some node
    if (!change.value.focusInline && change.value.selection.focusOffset === 0) {
      //Find the index of the node
      const textNodeIndex = change.value.focusBlock.nodes.findIndex(
        node => node.key === change.value.focusText.key
      );
      //check the node before it to see if its an inline
      const upcomingNode = change.value.focusBlock.nodes.get(textNodeIndex - 1);
      if (Inline.isInline(upcomingNode)) {
        //put me at the end of the inline
        return change.extendToEndOf(upcomingNode);
      }
    }
  };
```

I was hoping someone could help me understand whats going wrong here and possibly explain what I am misunderstanding. I also created a [barebones jsfiddle with my plugin](https://jsfiddle.net/fj9dvhom/963/). You'll notice if you attempt to erase the "p" at the end of "@help" it will prevent you from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `this.setState({value: change.value})` in onChange function.

Slate Editor shall be considered as a controlled component.

Comment: I don't have access to this.setState in the plugin where onChange is defined.

Comment: you can likely pass a reference to the editor into the plugin via props or some other mechanism.